# Interactive logon: Prompt user to change password before expiration

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, active-directory

How can i get "Interactive logon: Prompt user to change password before expiration" days from C# Active directory properties?

Refer screenshot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/96ugm.png

Answer (score 0):

Group policy just applies registry settings to the computer or user. In this case:

`PasswordExpiryWarning` in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon`

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc957396.aspx

You can read it using:

```
int expiry = (int)Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine
             .OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon")
             .GetValue("PasswordExpiryWarning");
```

Comment: Is it possible to get it from Active directory server instead of Registry.LocalMachine?...bcz i have used LDAP form authentication in my application...

Comment: Nope, its not possible to read this from LDAP. It's not stored in active directory, the policies are stored under \\domain\SYSVOL\domain\Policies.